# DB2, ORACLE and SQL Server. UPDATE with SUBSELECT FOR UPDATE, avoid deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, db2

I have a tool and you can use it with DB2, Oracle, and MySQL.Now I have many deadlocks (SQL Server), and I want to avoid this.I have the following SQL update query

```
UPDATE [TABA] 
SET FIELDA = 0  
WHERE FIELDB = ? AND FIELDC = ?;
```

and this SQL update query caused deadlock. I want change it to SUBSELECT_FOR_UPDATE e.g.

```
UPDATE [TABA] 
SET FIELDA = 0  
WHERE FIELDB IN (SELECT FIELDB 
                 FROM [TABA] WHERE FIELDE = 600 AND FIELDG = 5885328 FOR UPDATE);
```

I do not know how to use FOR UPDATE in a SUBSELECT (DB2, ORacle and SQL Server).

Comment: The table is always the same "TABA", why do you need subselect and "FOR UPDATE"? In case of Oracle simply use the 1st query.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL Server i know

```
UPDATE [TABA] 
SET FIELDA = 0 
WHERE FIELDB IN (SELECT FIELDB 
                 FROM [TABA] with (updlock) where FIELDE = 600 AND FIELDG = 5885328);
```

Missing DB2 and Oracle